# Kafka 0.10: what's wrong with my consumer?

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

i'm trying to do some easy demo in kafka-0.10.0.0.
my producer is ok , but consumer maybe not correct, code as below.

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "group1");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");


        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topictest2"));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);


            for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) { 

                 List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition); 

                 for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : partitionRecords) {

                     System.out.println("Thread = "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ");
                     System.out.printf("partition = %d, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s",record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                     System.out.println("\n");
                }
                // consumer.commitSync();
                 long lastOffset = partitionRecords.get(partitionRecords.size() - 1).offset(); 
                 consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(lastOffset + 1))); 
            }

        }
```

but when i run this demo, No output! what is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks valid.

I think the program is just waiting for new messages because 
`auto.offset.reset` default is **latest**

If you have some messages in that topic and want to read them, try to add

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
```

to start reading topic from beginning and reset your group.id to something unique to make sure it won't continue from saved offset or do not commit offset at all. Once its there for a group id the `auto.offset.reset` is skipped.

```
props.put("group.id", "group."+UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```